# How to order tasks by importance in microsoft todo task graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-todo

I'm trying to programmatically retrieve the same information which the Microsoft ToDo desktop and mobile app display.
While I'm able to load the tasks, I'm not able to retrieve them in the same order.
In the app you can sort by importance, which probably uses some internal priority, which is adapted if you move tasks around.
I can't find such a field in the API specs though:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todotask?view=graph-rest-1.0

Is there any way to retrieve this kind of sorting as well via the API?

E.g. I saw that for the planner and its tasks there's an `orderHint`, I guess I'm looking for something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

By the importance field, you could use OData params filter or orderBy by "importance" column, as per the example below:

[image: Postman Screenshot of request parameters w/ OData]

---

Although, I strongly believe you don't want "importance" ordering, but the custom order as you've mentioned "if you move tasks around", for this, I have raised a detailed question here: [How to get and set custom order on MS To-Do using GraphAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851210/how-to-get-and-set-custom-order-on-ms-to-do-using-graphapi) mentioning how To-Do application works, with the "OrderDateTime" field.